# Auto generated (also auto increment) input field in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="bill_no" placeholder="Bill no" />
  <input type="text" name="patient_name" placeholder="Patient name" />
  <input type="date" name="bill_date">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
// Connecting to database 
    include "connect.php"; 
if (ISSET($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
       $bill_no = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['bill_no']); 
       $patient_name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['patient_name']); 
       $bill_date = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['bill_date']); 
       $query = "INSERT INTO bills(bill_no, patient_name, bill_date) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 
       $stmt = $con->prepare($query); 
       $stmt->bind_param("sss", $bill_no, $patient_name, $bill_date ); 
       $stmt->execute(); } 
       $con->close(); 
?>
```

I've a form which can be accessed at a time by multiple users. In my form I need a field **(say bill_no)** that should be auto incremented when ever the user **opens** the form, if the user doesn't submit the form or unexpectedly closes the browser window the value should be destroyed and should not be saved in my database. The **bill_no** should be shown immediately if the user opens the form which should be incremented by one that of previous bill_no. Thank you.

Comment: put your code please , what have you tried yet.

Comment: @rahul actually I don't have any idea how to solve my problem. I just have the concept.

Comment: did you mean without submit the form, the ID value incremented automatically ?? for the next user

Comment: @KarthiVenture Yes, and if the user didn't submit the form or closes the browser the value should not be saved

Comment: can you post php code

Comment: Uh escaping **and** prepared queries? Pick **one**

Answer (score 1):

try this one it may help you. after submit it will redirect your page so old data cloud not be insert at second time

```
$newURL="youfile.php";
if (ISSET($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
       $bill_no = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['bill_no']); 
       $patient_name = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['patient_name']); 
       $bill_date = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['bill_date']); 
       $query = "INSERT INTO bills(bill_no, patient_name, bill_date) VALUES (?,?,?)";
       $stmt = $connection->prepare($query); 
       $stmt->bind_param("sss", $bill_no, $patient_name, $bill_date ); 
       $stmt->execute();
     header('Location: '.$newURL);
 } 
$connection->close();
```

more learn about [HEADER in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score -1):

on form page create a select query to fetch your bill no. save it in database and show it on input value of your bill no. by increment(+1).

This can be the logic and check on the back-end (before inserting into database) if the bill no is already in the database then redirect back to the form with some error message "last bill no. already exists" sort of then let him submit the form because we have already set up the bill no dynamically.

Try this